# What RegEx to use to include all subroutes except for specific urls

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'm terribly at regex and I could use some help in building a regular expression so that I can target all subroutes on a specific domain and at the same time exclude a couple of specific subroutes.

The regex is to be used in JavaScript (as page targeting within the Optimizely software).

Should allow:

- `www.mydomain.com/**/*`
- `www.mydomain.com/foo/**/*`

Should not allow

- `www.mydomain.com/foo/bar/**/*`
- `www.mydomain.com/baz/**/*`

The part I am most struggling with is allowing everything, also allowing everything ending with `/foo/...` except when it is ending with `/foo/bar/...`, while also excluding anything ending with `/baz/...`.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, they helped me in finding the solution myself:

`domain\.com((?=\/foo)|(?!\/foo\/bar\/|\/baz\/)).*`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion to exclude specific patterns:

```
^www\.mydomain\.com\/(?!(?:foo\/bar|baz)\/).*\/.*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/w6MQA0/1

Answer (score 1):

Use this `(www.mydomain.com\/)(([a-z]+\/)*(foo\/))?\*\*\/\*`. It should work.

It's working in this scenario:

```
`www.mydomain.com/**/*`
or
`www.mydomain.com/<any params may or may not be>/foo/**/*`
```

Code:

```
var regx = /(www.mydomain.com\/)(([a-z]+\/)*(foo\/))?\*\*\/\*/g;
ar = ['www.mydomain.com/**/*', 'www.mydomain.com/foo/**/*','www.mydomain.com/foo/bar/**/*','www.mydomain.com/baz/**/*']
regx.test(ar[0]) // true
regx.test(ar[1]) // true
regx.test(ar[2]) // false
regx.test(ar[3]) // false
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/05vUz8/1

Other regex for referrance:

1. https://regex101.com/r/NoDI87/1
2. https://regex101.com/r/HFaQo0/1